# (Proof Verification) Proof of the number of unique cosets of a subgroup H of G

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

I was trying to prove that the number of unique left cosets of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is $\frac{n(G)}{n(H)}$

This is what I came up with, but I am unsure if it is a valid proof:

Let $G$ be a group, let $H$ be some subgroup of $G$

Consider the left coset $xH$ of $H$.

Suppose the size of $H$ is $n$.

Then $xH = (xh_1, xh_2, ... , xh_n)$

We can construct all equivalent cosets as follows:

Let $y_i = x({h_i}^{-1})$

Then ${y_i}{h_i}{h_j} = x{h_j}$ For all integral $j$ such that $1\leq j\leq n $ .

There are clearly also only $n$ options for $i$.

Therefore there are $n$ equivalent cosets of $xH$.

Now we must show that any equivalent coset of $xH$ also satisfies this condition (specifically, we must prove the converse of the result we have just proven above).

Suppose $xH$ = $yH$.

Then $xh_i = yh_k $ for some integral $i, k $

Then $y = xh_i{h_k}^{-1}$

H is a subgroup, therefore ${h_i}{h_k}^{-1} = h_m$ for some $m$.

Thus it is proved.

Therefore, the number of distinct cosets of $H$ is $\frac{n(G)}{n(H)}$

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the bijection $$\begin{align}\varphi: H &\to xH\\h &\mapsto xh\end{align}$$

then every coset of $H$ in $G$ has the same number of elements of $H$. If by definition $(G:H)$ is the number of cosets then it follows that $|G| = |H| (G:H)$, where $|G| = n (G)$.

Comment: Forgive me if I have missed something obviously crucial in this answer, but how does this answer my question?

Comment: This is Lagrange's Theorem. You are computing the index of a group $H$, and through the equivalence relation, which is a partition this is how you prove it (the theorem).

Comment: So there is one and only one way to prove the thoerem? Also your answer says ' If by definition $\frac{n(G)}{n(H)}$ is the number of cosets.' My question is just about whether or not the proof I have given for the fact that the number of cosets being $\frac{n(G)}{n(H)}$ is valid or not. I realize it is called 'Lagrange's Theorem' what I am asking is if the proof I have presented in my question  is valid. I apologize if there has been a misunderstanding.

Comment: The symbol $(G:H)$ represents the index, which is the number of cosets of $H$ in $G$. Your proof will end up showing this bijection and that the equivalence relation is a partition.

Comment: I see, so is my proof technically valid? If it shows that these two facts are true?

Comment: Yes. You could write it better though, by expliciting the bijection and stating what you're trying to get at. The core of the argument is what me and lhf have said.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems incomplete and too complicated.
Your argument seems to address only point 2 below.

You need to prove that:

1. $G$ is the union of all cosets.
2. Two cosets are either equal or disjoint.
3. Every coset has the exactly same number of elements as $H$ has.

These will imply that $n(G)=n(H) k$, where $k$ is the number of cosets.

Comment: My proof definitely covers (3.) and you've just told me it seems to address (2.), (1.) follows from (2.) and (3.)

Comment: Could you point out a mathematical / logical problem with my proof? Or perhaps if it is too complicated, point out at which point it does not seem to be coherent? Because your answer is essentially giving me a step by step method to prove Lagrange's theorem, however, I was attempting to prove the theorem directly using my own method, as a consequence I do believe my proof does implicitly prove (1.) (2.) and (3.). Again, if you think otherwise could you please tell me why?

Comment: @moorish, where do you explicitly address points 1 and 3?

Comment: A left coset is of the form $xH = (xh_1,xh_2, ... , xh_n)$ where $x$ is some element in $G$, $xh_i \neq xh_j $ for all $i \neq j$

Comment: Every coset is of this form. As I did not specify what $x$ was, only that it is an element of $G$.

Comment: Also, I re-emphasize that I do not believe you need to $explicitly$ prove (1.) , (2.), (3.) to prove that the number of distinct cosets of a set $G$ is $\frac{n(G)}{n(H)}$ which is why I would have liked, if you disagree with this proof, to point out where exactly within the proof itself you sense something is logically incoherent.